# How to write a single query for multiple data manipulation in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have to insert values from jsp form to database table and to the same table I need to insert values for two columns from 2 different tables.

Here is the code:

```
public class ForgotPassWordDAO {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public void createSecretQnA(ForgotPassWord forgotPassWord) {
        String sql =  "INSERT INTO forgotpassword (PwdId,SecretQuestion1,SecretAnswer1,SecretQuestion2,SecretAnswer2)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";  // Here am inserting form values to database.
        String sql1="INSERT INTO forgotpassword (CustId) SELECT CustId FROM signup";// Here am trying to get value from another table and insert
        String sql2="INSERT INTO forgotpassword (LoginId) SELECT LoginId FROM login"; // Here am trying to get value from another table and insert
        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            ps.setInt(1, forgotPassWord.getId());
            ps.setString(2, forgotPassWord.getSq1());
            ps.setString(3, forgotPassWord.getAnSq1());
            ps.setString(4, forgotPassWord.getSq2());
            ps.setString(5, forgotPassWord.getAnSq2());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps1.executeUpdate();
            ps2.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

        catch (NullPointerException e1){

        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

But on each executeUpdate() its incrementing and the values from the form are stored in one row and  in the next row the values from the signup and login tables are getting stored. How to make all this get stored in a single row? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about fetching the custId and loginId via a select-query and inserting then with only one insert-query?

Comment: @Narmer so how to solve this?

Comment: @irene can u just let me know how to do that??

Comment: Narmer is right, you need some condition to select a singe loginId. Which Login Id do you need? Maybe you should pass it as Parameters in your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing 3 inserts, so at least 3 rows are created. Also, when you do `SELECT CustId FROM signup`, how can you ensure that only one and the right value of `CustId` is taken from `signup` table? With this query you are fetching all the `CustId`. Same goes for `login` table and query.

To merely resolve your problem you have to create a single query:

```
String sql =  "INSERT INTO forgotpassword (PwdId,SecretQuestion1,SecretAnswer1,SecretQuestion2,SecretAnswer2,CustId,LoginId)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,(SELECT CustId FROM signup),(SELECT LoginId FROM login))"; 
                                                                                                                ^      ^                                  ^                            ^
```

but I don't think you have thought this enough.

There should be something like:

```
SELECT LoginId FROM login WHERE CustId=? //Here I'm guessing, I don't know your tables.
```

The point is to get the correct value both in `login` table and `signup` table that corresponds to the user who forgot his password. This can be easily done with a `WHERE` clause (supposing your foreign key are setted correctly).

---

**EDIT**

As per your comment I'm going to clarify the way you should add your new user.

First of all you need to create the new user, so as soon as the information needed is sent and checked you insert a new row in `signup` table. But wait to execute the query.

You need the `CustId`. Because is an auto-increment column, you don't know which value MySQL created. You must fetch it and you can do it directly when you create the new user adding a parameter to the prepared statement:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlForNewUser, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);  
pstmt.executeUpdate();  
ResultSet keys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();    
keys.next();  
custId = keys.getInt(1);
```

Now you have the new user Id and can use it to insert the other values:

```
String sql =  "INSERT INTO forgotpassword (PwdId,SecretQuestion1,SecretAnswer1,SecretQuestion2,SecretAnswer2,CustId,LoginId)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,(SELECT CustId FROM signup WHERE CustId = ?),(SELECT LoginId FROM login WHERE CustId = ?))";
//...
ps.setString(6, custId);
ps.setString(7, custId);
```

Comment: how to fetch the id??

Comment: Add your tables definition in your question. You should have a common column between the tables and use that to fetch the right Id.

Comment: actually its against a registration form which on submission his first name last name, mailid, mobile no sits in signup table. Signup has a primary key CustId (which is a foreign key for both login ang forgotpassword tables). Username and password sits in login table. Login table has a primary key LoginId which is a foreign key for Forgotpassword table. and secret question and answer will sit in forgotpassword table. so in order to pass these foreign keys CustId and LoginId some values am struggling. Please help me so that i can fetch these id's and put it in where clause as u ve shown

Comment: and all the primary keys are auto incremented

Comment: so is it like somewhere i need to do id=rs.getInt(CustId) and fetch it from the tables and then use it in where clause?

Comment: Exactly. First of all you need the `CustId`, which is the only common parameter between the tables. I don't know your logic but usually a e-mail address is prompted to the user and then you search the `CustId` from `signup` table using it. You then use it in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: oh k i will try this way and get back to you thanks a ton for the ideas. If it works i will be glad thank u

Comment: In your case, if I understand well, you are inserting the secret question and answer. Depending on your current flow you may or not have the user ID. If you are registering him you may not yet have inserted the new user; In this case you first insert the user and then the questions. If the user is logged in you can retrieve the ID from the session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61552/discussion-between-user3349720-and-narmer).

Comment: i thought of making the EmailId column unique to the signup table and getting the CustId through it